# Reputation Cap not being enforced?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The reputation cap is supposed to be 200? I'm at 533 on the second day. That shouldn't be possible? Am I misunderstanding how reputation caps work?

Comment: I know I hit the repcap because of the badge I received, but I also surpassed 300 rep on my first day, which as I understand it, should be impossible.

Comment: What time counts as a new day?

Comment: @Mew Midnight UTC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that reputation cap only affects upvotes, not acceptance bonuses.

It's actually perfectly your highest possible reputation. You started at 101 reputation. Then, for 2 days, you earned 400 reputation putting you at 501. Then, you have two answers accepted (+30), and accepted one answer (+2), ending at a nice 533. Well, 532 if you include the one downvote you've cast.

As a test, I gave you an upvote on a post of yours. Your reputation still looks like 533, and I don't think it's going to change.

Comment: Ahh, the acceptance bonuses stuff was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Reputation gained from accepted answers and bounties is immune from the cap. If you check your reputation report (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/reputation) you should see 200 coming from votes and the rest from acceptances.